# How should I use Viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

I'm making an app with 2 table views. the first has a bunch of cells which lead to the next table view (which can have different data depending on which cell is selected). 
My question is, is it better to have a bunch of view controllers for the second menu (1 for each cell selection, or to have one view controller and load different data on it.

Comment: This is a very standard ios pattern. Basically you need to use a Navigation Controller, and then the first Table View Controller becomes your "root view". Selecting a cell then seques to a second table view controller, and adds a back button. So, just two Table View Controllors. Look at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewAndDataModel/TableViewAndDataModel.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no right or false. However, I would recommend you to use different viewcontrollers. Especially if you are using a storyboard, this is very straightforward. Just connect your different cell types with the appropriate viewcontroller and pass your data in the `-performSegueWithIdentifier:` method.
Maybe if you would add some details about the kind of data etc. I could give you a more adequate answer.

**Edit:**

In this case it would actually make more sense to work with a single second tableviewcontroller, as the input format is always the same and the output is based on the input data. You could do something like this:

**FirstTableViewController.h**

```
@interface FirstTableViewController.h : UITableViewController

// array containing NSArrays which themselves contain NSStrings
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *textArrays;

@end
```

**FirstTableViewController.m**

```
@implementation FirstTableViewController

@synthesize textArrays;

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     return self.textArrays.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *Identifier = @"Your Identifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:Identifier];
    }

    NSArray *textArray = self.textArrays[indexPath.row];
    if (textArray != nil && [textArray isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        // configure cell
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)sender;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    SecondTableViewController *controller = [segue destinationViewController].
    controller.textArray = self.textArrays[indexPath.row];
}

@end
```

**SecondTableViewController.h**

```
@interface SecondTableViewController.h : UITableViewController

// array containing NSStrings
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *textArray;

@end
```

**SecondTableViewController.m**

```
@implementation SecondTableViewController

@synthesize textArray;

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     return self.textArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *Identifier = @"Your Identifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:Identifier];
    }

    NSString *text = self.textArray[indexPath.row];
    if (text != nil && [text isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        // configure cell, e.g. cell.textLabel.text = text;
    }

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Remember that there are always several ways to achieve something. This is just my way and it does not have to be yours. However, I hope this helps.

Comment: Its a very basic text viewer app that just has text in it. as of now there is a selection of about 5 cells in the first viewcontroller. I want each of them go into a second view controller with different texts. I used a customTableViewCell class to create the cells. I was thinking of putting an if statement in the second class viewDidLoad method with a public variable. (if the indexpath.row is 1 it will go to the second view controller and load the array specified under 1).

Comment: This is my first app (im just starting) so I might not be doing everything correctly. Please let me know if im doing anything wrong

Comment: So in the second viewcontroller you want to display a bunch of cells with texts which are saved in an array, right? Is the only difference between all viewcontrollers that they should display different texts? I still do not fully understand what you want to do. Could you maybe share your code or upload a screenshot of your storyboard, that would be helpful.

Comment: You got it. Its exactly what you are saying. The only difference is the text. Everything else is identical

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you understand the difference between a class and an instance of that class, i.e. an object. Typically, when a user taps on a cell in your first table, you'll create a new view controller *object*, load it up with whatever data it needs to display the content corresponding to the tapped cell, and push it onto your navigation stack. When the user is done looking at that content, they hit the "back" button to switch back to the previous view controller. When that happens, the "detail" view controller is normally deallocated because no other objects are referencing it. When the user taps another cell, the process repeats -- a new view controller is created, configured, pushed, and eventually dismissed.

So, that means you'll have two view controller *classes*, and at any given time one or two view controller *objects* (not counting a navigation controller), but over time you end up creating many instances of the detail view controller class. You *could* create just a single instance of the detail view controller and reuse it as necessary, but there's no real advantage to doing so and it ends up being another thing that the main view controller needs to keep track of.

Of course, if different cells in your main table could lead to significantly different *kinds* of data that need to be displayed in different ways, then you might end up with more than just the two view controller classes. In that case, when the user taps a cell you'd have to figure out which kind of detail view controller you want to use and then instantiate that one. For example, tapping one cell might lead to information about a person while another might lead to a picture and a third might lead to a map.

Answer (score 0):

I would use 2 TableViewController and Custom Cells to do this. Basically once the user chooses a cell on the first TableView, you populate the second Table View with the appropriate data and dequeue the appropriate custom cell to display the data.